# How to iterate or select a item from list in autoit

Tags: list, autoit

I have a list of items under class name SysListView32.

How do I select a particular item in AutoIt?

I am unable to select an item under the list and the AutoIt info tool is not providing any data.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

See [GuiListView user defined functions Reference](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/GUI%20GuiListView%20Management.htm) and most likely _GUICtrlListView_FindInText() to find the index of an item with the desired text and _GUICtrlListView_SetItemState() to select an item.